# Is there an implemented function similar to the toString() function in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get an Object within a Collection as a String without calling a function for it.
e.G.:
In java i can

```
System.out.print(objVarXY)
```

and the compiler will automatically call the objVarXY.toString() function (if implemented)

in VBA something like this

```
Debug.Print parameterListe.LList.Item(1)
```

will cause an error.

```
Debug.Print parameterListe.LList.Item(1).toString
```

will work, if i implemented a toString Subfunction.
But what if i dont know what kind of object will be inside my LList collection?

Comment: There's no equivalent in VBA - objects do not have a prototypical `toString()` method (ormaybe implement a default member which would produce a string).   If you're only dealing with your own classes then you could implement that, but "built-in" types would be an issue.

Comment: The default implementation of `toString` outputs the type's name. If you can't modify the class and override `toString`, you have the exact same problem in Java that you have in VBA. Something, somewhere, needs to know how to represent that object as a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Debug.Print` will implicitly attempt coerce the given *value expression* into a `String` for output.

When you `Debug.Print` an object, VBA attempts to `Let`-coerce the object into a value - if the object doesn't have a *default member* that ultimately yields a value that can be implicitly converted to a `String`, then you get run-time error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method" if the class doesn't have a *default member*.

If the object is user code (i.e. your own class module), and if it makes sense to do so, you could add a default member yourself, and have the class responsible for knowing how to represent itself as a `String` (note that the VB attribute is hidden in the VBE code panes, and must be edited outside the VBE - unless you're using [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck), in which case you can simply add a `@DefaultMember` annotation and synchronize annotations/attributes):

```
'@DefaultMember
Public Function ToString() As String
Attribute ToString.VB_UserMemId = 0
    '...
End Function
```

But all this does is give the class the ability to be essentially treated as a `String`, through implicit member calls. I'd call that something like an abuse a language feature (it's through this mechanism that `Debug.Print Excel.Application` outputs the application's `Name`, or `Debug.Print adoConnection` outputs the connection's `ConnectionString` property), since as you noted, you might as well just invoke that `ToString` method explicitly.

If the object doesn't know how to represent itself as a `String`, then *something, somewhere* will have to. In Java (IIRC) and .NET this would essentially be the default `ToString` implementation:

```
Debug.Print TypeName(objVarXY)
```

...which is rather useless, but that's essentially what `ToString` does by default.

Whether you're writing Java, C#, or VBA, there needs to be code responsible for knowing how to represent `objVarXY` as a `String`.

Sadly VBA doesn't do fancypants pattern matching, so we can't `Select Case TypeOf obj` like in C# (it only recently got that ability - don't know about Java), and since `Select Case TypeName(obj)` wouldn't be type-safe, I'd go with `If...ElseIf`:

```
Public Function Stringify(ByVal obj As Object) As String
    If TypeOf obj Is Something Then
        Dim objSomething As Something
        Set objSomething = obj ' cast to Something interface
        Stringify = objSomething.SomeProperty

    ElseIf TypeOf obj Is SomethingElse Then
        Dim objSomethingElse As SomethingElse
        Set objSomethingElse = obj ' cast to SomethingElse interface
        Stringify = objSomethingElse.AnotherProperty & "[" & objSomethingElse.Foo & "]"

    'ElseIf TypeOf obj Is ... Then
    '    ...
    Else
        ' we don't know what the type is; return the type name.
        Stringify = TypeName(obj)
    End If
End Function
```

---

Obviously if the collection always involves classes that you own, the better solution is to have each object know how to represent itself as a `String` value.

But, having user classes expose a `ToString` method on their *default interface* isn't ideal: since we don't know what type we're getting from the collection, all we have is `Object` and a late-bound call - and no compile-time guarantee that the class implements a `ToString` method, and no compiler warning if we try to invoke, say, `ToStrnig`.

The solution is to *not* put `ToString` on the classes' default interface, and formalize the behavior with some `IString` class module, which might look like this:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function ToString() As String
End Funtion
```

Yup, that's the whole class.

Now the user classes that need to be representable as strings, can do this:

```
Option Explicit
Implements IString

Private Function IString_ToString() As String
    ' todo: implement the method!
End Function
```

And now we can have early-bound assurance that the objects have a `ToString` method:

```
Dim o As Object
For Each o In MyCollection
    If TypeOf o Is IString Then
        Dim s As IString
        Set s = o 'cast to IString interface
        Debug.Print s.ToString
    Else
        Debug.Print TypeName(o)
    End If
Next
```

At the end of the day there's no magic, regardless of what language you're using.

Comment: Wow i didnt expect such a useful hint.
Thank you very much. In my case i know my Collection will always have the same type of objects but it is good to know how to handle different cases aswell.

In Java i almost everytime implement toString because it is very handy in almost any case. In lots of realistic practical cases most objects have one main variable value which indicates very well what the object represents. Maybe it is justmy personal coding style but i realy missed this in in vba. It is also handy for exporting Data in txt files you can directly understand by reading easily.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that does not exist in VBA there are only the [Type conversion functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions) like `CStr()` to convert eg. an `Integer` into a `String`.

If you eg need to convert a `Collection` into an `Array` you will need to use a function for that.

---

> But what if I don't know what kind of object will be inside my `LList` collection

Then you will need to determine which object it is (you would probably expect eg 5 different possible objects) and do something like a `Select Case` for each different object type to convert this to a `String`.